# What does byte_407030[ecx] mean?

Tags: ida, assembly

I came across the following instruction in IDA:

```
movsx edx, byte_407030[ecx]
```

`byte_407030` is `25h`. Is it trying to access some memory location? I know that `ecx` is storing a counter in a for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets go step by step:

```
movsx
```

This is a specialized move instruction it moves a value from source of a smaller size (in your case, a byte) to a destination of a potentially larger size (in your case, a double word), preserving the sign bit by an operation called [sign-extending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).

This means that if the byte was a negative integer then the destination will also be a negative integer. This is a bit more complex then simply copying the last bit because of the way negative integers are encoded (which is called [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).

```
edx
```

The first operand of a `mov` instruction is the destination target. In this case it's the double-word register `edx`. This is were the data is moved to.

```
byte_407030[ecx]
```

The second operand is the source operand. This is where the data is moved from. Please note that although the instruction is `mov`, the value also remains in the source location. Calling it "copy" might have been a better idea ;).

IDA's syntax here is similar to C's syntax. This will dereference the memory region at address `0x407030` plus the value of `ecx` and fetch a byte from there. In case `ecx` is `11h`, the final address would be `0x407041`.

**summary**

This instruction will take the byte value at memory address of `0x407030+ecx`, sign extend it to dword (4 bytes in most architectures) and assign that final value into register `edx`